# Spring Integration: Inbound File Adapter drops files when service restarts

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

We're using the `S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` feature of Spring Integration to locally sync and then send messages for any files retrieved from an S3 bucket.

Before syncing, we apply a couple of `S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` filters (to check the file's TimeModified and Hash/ETag) to make sure we only sync "new" files.

Note: We use the `JdbcMetadataStore` table to persist the record of the files that have previously made it through the filters (using a different `REGION` for each filter).

Finally, for the `S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` local filter, we have a <s>`S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`</s> `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` -- again on TimeModified and again persisted but in a different region.

The issue is: if the service is restarted *after* the file has made it through the 1st filter but *before* the message source successfully sent the message along, we essentially *drop* the file and never actually process it.

What are we doing wrong? How can we avoid this "dropped file" issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` for the `localFilter` since `S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` is not going to work there.

Let see how you use those filters in the configuration! I wonder if switching to the `ChainFileListFilter` for your remote files helps you somehow.

See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-reading

**EDIT**

> if the service is restarted after the file has made it through the 1st filter but before the message source successfully sent the message along

I think Gary is right: you need a transaction around that polling operation which includes filter logic as well.

See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-metadata-store

This way the TX is not going to be committed until the message for a file leaves the polling channel adapter. Therefore after restart you simply will be able to synchronize the rolled back files again. Just because they are not present in the store for filtering.

Comment: Won't the poller need to be transactional so that the writes to the filters' JDBC stores will not be committed until the downstream operations complete? This also implies only DirectChannels are used (no async processing).

Comment: Yes, it's a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` as the `localFilter`. My mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get transactions working! The following 2 resources were great: 
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-integration-transaction (Basic Setup)
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html (Advanced Stuff)